# Exception ValueError: 'I/O operation on uninitialized object' in

Tags: python, automation

We have a small automation test process called run.py at work and inside the file there is a class called

```
class flushfile(io.TextIOWrapper):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def write(self, x):
        self.f.write(x)
        self.f.flush()
```

it gives this error:

```
Exception ValueError: 'I/O operation on uninitialized object' in
```

Every time we run the tests but it does not seem to affect anything. The context of the class is that we are flushing the buffer after printing to a text file as well as the command line.

```
sys.stdout = flushfile(sys.stdout)
```

Is how it is called in the code.

For the life of me I can't figure out what it might be.

Comment: Wild guess: I bet you need to call `io.TextIOWrapper.__init__` inside your own `__init__`.

Comment: I should mention that the file containing this class is not actually a class in itself. It is just a script that walks through folders and reads texts files then creates command line arguments to run the command line version of our program. So while the overarching program most certainly has an __init__ I don't have access to that code from my current position.

Comment: So you're saying you don't have access to the `def __init__(self, f): self.f = f` code that you've written above?

Comment: "Call to `__init__` of super class is missed" is another warning directly related to the `__init__` in the flushfile class. Pycharm warned me about it just now.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I misinterpreted your comment. Let me try that. I thought you meant the process that is run by the file needs the code you mentioned. Kind of bone headed mistake....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add `flush()` method in your wrapper:

```
class flushfile(io.TextIOWrapper):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def write(self, x):
        self.f.write(x)
        self.f.flush()
    def flush(self):
        self.f.flush()
```

A simple test is:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = flushfile(sys.stdout)
print("TEST")
```

Without `flush()` you will got the error when script dead and try to call `flush()` of *new* `sys.stdout`.

Anyway with the original version if you recover `stdout` before exit you can have the same result:

```
import sys
orig = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = flushfile(sys.stdout)
print("TEST")
sys.stdout = orig
```

---

**EDIT**

Maybe you don't need to wrapper for file object but just a new `write()` method. Python is first a functional programming language and a more pythoninc way to do what you want to do is change `sys.stdout.write` method. Follow an implementation example:

```
def make_write_flusher(f):
    orig = f.write
    def new_write(data):
        orig(data)
        f.flush()
    f.write = new_write

import sys
make_write_flusher(sys.stdout)
print("TEST")
```

A final consideration is that if you call `super` in your original implementation that fix the issue but the real think is that you don't really use the wrapper and both of following implementations give the same result. In Python interface doesn't really mater what is important if a attribute/methods is present and what is when you use it.

```
class flushfile(io.TextIOWrapper):
    def __init__(self, f):
        super(flushfile,self).__init__(f)
        self.f = f
    def write(self, x):
        self.f.write(x)
        self.f.flush()

class flushfile():
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def write(self, x):
        self.f.write(x)
        self.f.flush()
    def flush(self):
        self.f.flush()
```

Comment: If you have time could you maybe explain this to me like I'm 2 years old? As I understand it stdout is the output that you see on the command line from things like input() and raw_input(). That means that when I pass sys.stdout as a parameter to a class it gives output control to that class? And since sys.stdout is used for all output when something ELSE tries to output to the command line the exception is thrown? 

I hope I am not completely off :p

Comment: You are quite far from the true.... :) You must have a look to `sys.stdout` as the global variable where is stored the file used to print standard output: in other words where `print()` function write. When you set `sys.stdout` to `flushfile(sys.stdout)` you change the global standard output file to your wrapper. The only method that you call in your test `write` but when the script terminate python try to flush and close standard output and so your `flushfile(sys.stdout)` that have a `flush()` method from `io.TextIOWrapper` interface that raise the error.

Comment: Maybe you don't really need of a wrapper for the object but a wrapper for the function can be enough. I'll edit my answer by that solution.

Comment: Ah dang I was far off. Thank you for the explanation!